# R object doesn't stores correctly on runtime environment

Tags: r

I'm currently reading "Hands-on Programming with R", part II where we create a deck of cards. In the chapter 6 we create a closure so that the functions and objects are stored in other R environment and doesn't need any objects in the Global Environment to work properly. I'm having problems assuring that the object "BJDECK" from where all the process is derived (shuffle and deal functions) is being represented correctly in this new environment.

So far, this is the process:

1. I import deck.csv, a data frame with 52 rows and 3 variables ("faces", "suits", "value")
2. I change the values of the cards by running this to match a blackjack deck:

```
deck <- data.frame(
  face = rep(c("ace","king","queen","jack", 10:2), 4),
  suit = rep(c("heart","diamond","spade","club"), each=13)
)
bjdeck <- deck
bjdeck$value[bjdeck$face %in% c("king", "queen", "jack")] <- 10
bjdeck$value[bjdeck$face == "ace"] <- NA ##Because an Ace value can be 1 or 11.
```

3. With this "bjdeck" object in GlobalEnv I run the following script:

```
setup <- function(abjdeck) { ##"abjdeck" stands for "a blackjack deck"
  BJDECK <- bjdeck  ##To create a copy of the original blackjack deck in the new environment.
  
  SHUFFLE <- function() {
    random <- sample(1:52, size = 52)
    assign("abjdeck", BJDECK[random, ], envir = parent.env(environment()))
  }
  
  DEAL <- function() {
    card <- abjdeck[1, ]
    assign("abjdeck", abjdeck[-1, ], envir = parent.env(environment()))
    card
  }
  
  list(deal = DEAL, shuffle = SHUFFLE, bjdeckorigin = BJDECK)
}

cards <- setup(bjdeck)  ##To visualize in GlobalEnv everything that setup function contains, as far as I understand.

deal <- cards$deal
shuffle <- cards$shuffle
bjdeckorigin <- cards$bjdeckorigin  ##I added this piece of code, because I was wondering how the BJDECK object from which the randomization was taking place was like.
```

4. So far, so good, in the GlobalEnv the object "bjdeckorigin" is a data frame with 52 observations and 3 variables (normal). Shuffle and deal work as intended.
5. The **problem** is that, when I clear the GlobalEnv, and then I run again the script in the third point, the "bjdeckorigin" is now a data frame with only 51 observations (and 3 variables). The first observation ("king", "spades", 10) is always lost. The shuffle and deal functions work fine, but if, for example, I ran:

```
replicate(52, deal())
```

The last value is NA, NA, NA, and this should be the last card on the deck (whatever it may be). This replicate function returns the proper values when I test it before I clean the GlobalEnv.

I've tried everything I know (and I'm a complete begginer) to figure it out, but I keep getting the same result.

I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly are you clearing the global environment? You're deleting everything including the `cards` variable you create and are just running `setup()` again? But `bjdeck` doesn't exist any more? It's not clear to me what exactly you are running.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, I remove all the objects and functions in the GlobalEnv with `rm(list=ls())` on the console. I also have tried the broom that appears in the upper right cuadrant (where all the objects and functions in the environment appears). So everything, including bjdeck, doesn't exist anymore.
I do this because the book states that if you run `setup()` again, you'll have a self-contained deck of cards ready to play, in a environment out of the way of the GlobalEnv, to avoid overwrite of the functions or something like that.